# Google Sheet importXml by default converts time value in decimal value

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to get time value from html table by **importXml** google sheet function. When I set **cell format to "plain text"**, for value "**06:50**"in html table I get this value "**0.2847222222**" in sheet cell. I'm using xpath "//tr[1]/td[1]".

How do I get the same value as in html table in **plain text**? *Google "automatic" formatting displays correct value in "time" formatting* but I just want plain text because I use it in script.

Comment: You can try whit this function `=IMPORTXML("http://www.calculatehours.com/Military_Time_Conversion_Table_Sheet.html","//div[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]")`
Just copy and paste in Google sheet cell and set format to "plain text".

Answer (score 2):

Strings like "1:00" are automatically converted to a datetime object. Internally, dates and times are represented by a float on the scale 1 = one day, and this is what you get by directly imposing plain text format. To create a human-readable string, use [`text`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) formula:

```
=text(importxml(...), "HH:mm")
```

There are other variations like "hh:mm" or "h:mm": see the docs linked above.

Comment: In some cells in html I have comma separated values also with asterisk (i.e 12:20, 13:50*) and in that format "plain text" just works fine and give me a string value but when the value is single (just one value) the problem appears.

Comment: Sure, because "12:20, 13:50" is already a string; it has no meaning of time.  But "12:20" is the kind of a string that Sheets automatically interpret as time, and therefore converting it back to a string takes work. Again, this is not about imporxml; entering this text manually in a cell you would get the same behavior.

Comment: Sure, entering this text manually in cell Sheet interpret it as time but when you set it to "plain text" format, value remains the same. For `importXml` is not the case, value appears like decimal value.

Comment: Okay, there is a subtlety in behavior there, and I edited the first sentence. It was a tangential remark anyway.